# Better way to Dynamically Create New Objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, object

I have two objects defined something like this (simplified for sake of the question):

```
var firstObject = function(){ };
firstObject.prototype.doSomethingFirstObjectsDo();

var secondObject = function(){ };
secondObject.prototype.doSomethingSecondObjectsDo();
```

Next I have an Object Manager which works as a sort of interface for my main application to create objects:

```
var ObjectManager = function()
{
    this.create = {
        FIRST:firstObject,
        SECOND:secondObject
    };
};

ObjectManager.prototype.createObject = function(type)
{
    return new this.create[type]();
};
```

Finally an example of the main application using the Object Manager to Dynamically Create Either firstObjects or secondObjects:

```
var MainApplication = function(options)
{
    this.objectTypes = options.objectTypes;
    this.objManager = new ObjectManager();
};

MainApplication.prototype.createObjects = function()
{
    //Iterate through all the types this application needs to create
    for (var type in this.objectTypes)
    {
        var dynamicallyCreatedObject = this.objManager.createObject(type);
        //Do Something Else
    }
};
```

This approach works great, but has one disadvantage that I can see - being that you need to formally define the name of the Constructor Function for each Object "Type" that could be created.

In the event that I wanted to create a "thirdObject" - which would be already formally defined - I would also need to go back and add a reference to the "thirdObject"'s constructor function in the ObjectManager.

Ideally, I would like to remove the need for an "ObjectManager" and simply be able to dynamically call the constructor method with the "new" keyword like this:

```
//Inside MainApplication
for (var type in this.objectTypes)
{
    var dynamicallyCreateObject = new [type]();  //Invalid Syntax
};
```

Anybody have any thoughts on a better way to handle dynamically creating different objects in JavaScript using the "new" keyword?

---

Responding to Some Initial Comments:

I should have mentioned that the entire application is enclosed within an anonymous function.

```
(function(){
    //All of My Mentioned Code is Found Here
    $(document).ready(function(){
        mainApp = window.mainApp = new MainApplication(options);
    });
});
```

@casablanca: From what you are saying I believe I'll need to actually define a NameSpace inside the entire anonymous function, since once it finishes I have no real way to directly refer to that scope again.  I think I know what I need to do now, I was kind of hoping there was another way to work with that "new" keyword - but it doesn't seem like that is the case.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  That seems like an awful lot of code to do not much of anything.

Comment: I am working on making an application that is flexible enough to respond to a variety of data that will all need to be interpreted, displayed, and interacted with in completely different ways.  Setting up a nice interface like this makes it way easier for me to change code behavior for particular objects later, without having to go back and re-factor a other objects, such as an "ObjectManager".  I don't want my code to assume that it knows it is going to create a 'firstObject' or a 'secondObject' so hard-coding it is not an object for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understand your desire (and I'm not sure that I do) you can use the global `window` object in DOM 0 browsers, or create your own reference to the global scope, and use that to look up variables defined locally.

```
var $global = this;
var firstObject = function(){};

var objName = "firstObject";
var instance = new $global[objName];
```

Comment: Why is that any better than `var instance = new firstObject();`??  I don't understand the original question I guess.

Comment: @Pointy Because the original question asked how to loop through a list of 'object' names and create new instances from them.

Comment: Oh, OK.  I guess I still don't really get the whole point here, but what you say makes sense I guess.

Comment: Well sometimes you want to call functions or create objects dynamically.

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
var dynamicallyCreateObject = new [type]();
```

is almost correct, except you need an outer object to access properties. In the case that your constructors are global, you can use `window`:

```
var dynamicallyCreateObject = new window[type]();
```

Ideally, they should be within your own namespace, in which case you can do something similar:

```
var dynamicallyCreateObject = new MyNamespace[type]();
```